# What is the adjectival form of "paragon"?

Tags: adjectives, word-formation

If a person or thing is the exemplar of a particular virtue, you might say that they or it is exemplary or ideal; but the word "paragon" has a particular, even mythical connotation that none of the adjectives I've seen has. Could you say that something is "paragonic?" Perhaps "paragonal?"

Comment: This seems to be a lexical gap. But I haven't checked in OED. Though Wiktionary carries more headwords. // Making up pseudo-words to fill such gaps is non-standard and inadvisable for most purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Paragon* used to be an adjective, but it’s obsolete now:

> **paragon** *noun* & *adjective*
>  <sub>† ADJECTIVE</sub>
>  Of outstanding quality; perfect; pre-eminent. *Obsolete.*
> <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

The last of the example entries is from 1849:

> <sub>**1849**   O where is that paragon governess whom we want to keep them in
> order? 
> *—W. M. Thackeray,* Letter *30 August (1945) vol. II. 477*</sub>

So unless you’re writing a period piece, there is no adjective form of *paragon*. You can derive your own adjective by suffixing *-like* (*paragon-like*), but I’m not sure that would further your cause.

Comment: [***a paragon virtue***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+paragon+virtue%22) doesn't sound obsolete to me. Maybe they'd call that a noun used adjectivally, I dunno.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an adjectival form of 'paragon' that I can find.
The OP didn't ask the question directly, but says

> ... the word "paragon" has a particular, even mythical connotation that none of the adjectives I've seen has.

An adjective conveying that idea is

> **legendary**
>
> - very famous and admired or spoken about
> - from a legend
> - of or relating to an old story or set of stories from ancient times, or the stories that people tell about a famous event or person
> - of or describing someone who is very famous and admired, usually because of an ability in a particular area

From [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/legendary).

Comment: While legendary has the mythic implication, it loses the exemplary sense of paragon.

Comment: _Legendary_ certainly carries the 'prominent and admirable' sense (though 'pertaining to a legend' is obviously the root sense). CD even lists it first.

Comment: @Barmar today, someone is called 'legendary' if they are very, very good at what they do.

Comment: Yeah, that's a very recent sense. In my mind I link it with a movie like "Bill and Ted", but I'm not sure that's the right one.

Comment: @Barmar Bill and Ted's adventure wasn't a paragon. I get your understanding of 'legendary' but I'm applying the adjective to a person (although OP mentions 'thing' too).

Answer (score 1):

**Archetypal** is defined by [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/archetypal) as :

> Someone or something that is "archetypal" has all the most important
> characteristics of a particular kind of person or thing and is a
> perfect example of it.

The word has the exemplary meaning, without mythical or legendary connotation.